The state of the Next Js component is not updated
I am writing a page for the admin panel on the site. I have a component where I receive data from the backend (for example, products) and pass it to the Catalog Editor component. There, for example, I add a new product, invalidate the request, and using console.log I see that the request is re-executed, but the new data is not transferred to CatalogEditor. You need to refresh the page, and then the new data will be displayed in the component
Why it's happened?
AdminPanelComponent
import HomeEditor from "@/components/home-editor";
import AboutEditor from "@/components/about-editor";
import ContactEditor from "@/components/contact-editor";
import { useQuery } from "@tanstack/react-query";
import axios from "axios";
import CatalogEditor from "@/components/catalog-editor";
import { Product } from "@/types/product";
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";

interface AdminRightPanelProps {
  selectedMenu: string;
}
const CUSTOM_URL = process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_CUSTOM_URL || "";

export default function AdminRightPanel({
  selectedMenu,
}: AdminRightPanelProps) {
  const { data: homePageContent, isLoading: isHomePageLoading } =
    useQuery<HomePageContent>({
      queryKey: ["homePageContent"],
      queryFn: async () => {
        const response = await axios.get(`${CUSTOM_URL}api/content/home`);
        return response.data;
      },
    });
  const { data: aboutPageContent, isLoading: isAboutPageLoading } =
    useQuery<AboutPageContent>({
      queryKey: ["aboutPageContent"],
      queryFn: async () => {
        const response = await axios.get(`${CUSTOM_URL}api/content/about`);
        return response.data;
      },
    });
  const { data: contactPageContent, isLoading: isContactPageLoading } =
    useQuery<ContactPageContent>({
      queryKey: ["contactPageContent"],
      queryFn: async () => {
        const response = await axios.get(`${CUSTOM_URL}api/content/contact`);
        return response.data;
      },
    });
  const { data: products, isLoading: isProductsLoading } = useQuery<Product[]>({
    queryKey: ["products"],
    queryFn: async () => {
      const response = await axios.get(`${CUSTOM_URL}api/content/products`);
      return response.data;
    },
  });

  const [productItems, setProductItems] = useState<Product[]>([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (products) {
      setProductItems(products);
    }
  }, [products]);

  const isLoading =
    isHomePageLoading ||
    isAboutPageLoading ||
    isContactPageLoading ||
    isProductsLoading;

  if (isLoading) {
    return <div className="m-auto">Loading...</div>;
  }

  switch (selectedMenu) {
    case "home":
      return <HomeEditor content={homePageContent} />;
    case "catalog":
      return <CatalogEditor products={productItems} />;
    case "about":
      return <AboutEditor content={aboutPageContent} />;
    case "contact":
      return <ContactEditor content={contactPageContent} />;
  }
}

CatalogEditor component
import { useToast } from "@/hooks/use-toast";
import React, { useEffect, useRef, useState } from "react";
import Image from "next/image";
import { Product } from "@/types/product";
import { ImageDown } from "lucide-react";
import { Button } from "@/components/ui/button";
import {
  Select,
  SelectContent,
  SelectGroup,
  SelectItem,
  SelectLabel,
  SelectTrigger,
  SelectValue,
} from "@/components/ui/select";
import { useQueryClient } from "@tanstack/react-query";
import EditProductItem from "@/components/edit-product-item";

interface CatalogEditorProps {
  products: Product[];
}

const CUSTOM_URL = process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_CUSTOM_URL || "";

export default function CatalogEditor({ products }: CatalogEditorProps) {
  const { toast } = useToast();
  const queryClient = useQueryClient();
  const inputFileRef = useRef<HTMLInputElement | null>(null);

  const [category, setCategory] = useState<string | null>(null);
  const [base64Image, setBase64Image] = useState<string | null>(null);
  const [isButtonsDisabled, setIsButtonsDisabled] = useState<boolean>(false);
  const [isSubmitDisabled, setIsSubmitDisabled] = useState<boolean>(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    setIsButtonsDisabled(base64Image === null || base64Image === "");
  }, [base64Image]);

  useEffect(() => {
    setIsSubmitDisabled(
      base64Image === null ||
        base64Image === "" ||
        category === null ||
        category === "",
    );
  }, [base64Image, category]);

  function handleFileUpload() {
    inputFileRef.current?.click();
  }

  function handleFileChange(event: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) {
    const file = event.target.files?.[0];
    if (file) {
      const reader = new FileReader();
      reader.onloadend = () => {
        setBase64Image(reader.result as string);
      };
      reader.readAsDataURL(file);
    }
  }

  async function onSubmit() {
    if (base64Image && category) {
      const product: Product = {
        id: 0,
        base64image: base64Image,
        category: category,
      };

      fetch(`${CUSTOM_URL}api/content/products`, {
        method: "POST",
        headers: {
          "Content-Type": "application/json",
        },
        body: JSON.stringify(product),
      })
        .then((response) => {
          if (response.ok) {
            toast({
              title: "Дані оновлено!",
              description: "Зміни скоро будуть застосовані!",
            });
          } else {
            toast({
              title: "Помилка!",
              description: "Щось пішло не так :( Спробуйте пізніше!",
            });
          }
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          toast({
            title: "Помилка!",
            description: "Щось пішло не так :( Спробуйте пізніше!",
          });
        });

      setBase64Image(null);
      await queryClient.refetchQueries({ queryKey: ["products"] });
    }
  }

  return (
    <div className="w-full m-4">
      <div>
        <div className="flex w-full h-[240px] border border-[#18181B] p-4 rounded-lg my-2">
          <div
            className="flex flex-row min-w-[300px] cursor-pointer"
            onClick={handleFileUpload}
          >
            {base64Image ? (
              <div className="flex items-center justify-center h-[210px] w-full">
                <Image
                  className="col-span-1 max-h-[210px] object-contain"
                  width={300}
                  height={300}
                  src={base64Image}
                  alt="product"
                />
              </div>
            ) : (
              <div className="flex items-center justify-center h-[210px] w-[300px] border border-[#18181B]">
                <ImageDown /> <p className="ml-1">Завантажте товар</p>
              </div>
            )}
            <input
              ref={inputFileRef}
              id="picture"
              type="file"
              style={{ display: "none" }}
              onChange={handleFileChange}
            />
          </div>
          <div className="flex flex-col mx-4 w-full">
            <p className="text-lg mb-2 ">Категорія</p>
            <Select onValueChange={(value) => setCategory(value)}>
              <SelectTrigger className="w-full" disabled={isButtonsDisabled}>
                <SelectValue placeholder="Виберіть категорію" />
              </SelectTrigger>
              <SelectContent>
                <SelectGroup>
                  <SelectLabel>Категорії</SelectLabel>
                  <SelectItem value="sofa">Диван</SelectItem>
                  <SelectItem value="corner">Кут</SelectItem>
                  <SelectItem value="kit">Комплект</SelectItem>
                  <SelectItem value="ottoman">Тахта</SelectItem>
                  <SelectItem value="bed">Ліжко</SelectItem>
                </SelectGroup>
              </SelectContent>
            </Select>
            <Button
              className="mt-2 rounded-md font-[600] py-[20px] px-6 text-white bg-red-500 hover:bg-red-800 duration-300"
              onClick={() => setBase64Image("")}
              disabled={isButtonsDisabled}
            >
              Видалити продукт
            </Button>
          </div>
        </div>
        <Button
          className="mt-1 ml-1 rounded-[50px] font-[600] py-[20px] px-6 text-white bg-gray hover:bg-black duration-300"
          onClick={onSubmit}
          disabled={isSubmitDisabled}
        >
          Зберегти
        </Button>
      </div>

      <div className="flex justify-between my-4 text-lg mx-2">
        <p>Наявні продукти</p>
        <p>Кількість - {products.length}</p>
      </div>
      {products?.map((item, index) => (
        <EditProductItem key={index} item={item} />
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}


Can you [edit] to be more specific about what data is being updated but not seen in a component? We need clearer and more specific details.

I fixed it just moved queryClient.invalidateQueries() inside fetch and it work
async function onSubmit() {
    if (base64Image && category) {
      const product: Product = {
        id: 0,
        base64image: base64Image,
        category: category,
      };

      fetch(`${CUSTOM_URL}api/content/products`, {
        method: "POST",
        headers: {
          "Content-Type": "application/json",
        },
        body: JSON.stringify(product),
      })
        .then((response) => {
          if (response.ok) {
            queryClient.refetchQueries({ queryKey: ["products"] });
            toast({
              title: "Дані оновлено!",
              description: "Зміни скоро будуть застосовані!",
            });
          } else {
            toast({
              title: "Помилка!",
              description: "Щось пішло не так :( Спробуйте пізніше!",
            });
          }
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          toast({
            title: "Помилка!",
            description: "Щось пішло не так :( Спробуйте пізніше!",
          });
        });

      setBase64Image(null);
    }
  }

